# RVM certificate directories for cert.pem

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, openssl, rvm

I recently manually updated my cert.pem files with RVM as a routine maintenance procedure. This was after installing Yosemite and Xcode 6.1.

After running the command `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`

and calling `rvm osx-ssl-certs status all`

I got this back:

```
Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
Certificates for : Old.
Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
```

I know both `Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.` and
            `Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.`

One is from RVM and the other, from a Ruby install.

But what is `Certificates for : Old.`?

It looks like RVM is reading a certificate in a blank directory with no name? What is that and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

This phantom certificate `Certificates for : Old.` seems to have resolved itself with no intervention from me. It disappeared the next time I checked.